# как сохранять правильно в БД если один тот самый клиент будет клиентом у разных сотрудников а также с разных компаний?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

на сайте может быть много компаний
У компаний может быть много сотрудников
У сотрудников может быть много клиентов

так вот если сделать что клиент добавленный сотрудником сохранится в БД
если этот же клиент придет до второго сотрудника через время то сохранить его нужно повторно тоесть в БД будет 2 строчки того самого клиента имя и телефон а если будет много компаний и этот клиент к примеру будет у 100 компаниях тоесть 100 строк того самого телефона и имени это нормально?

Или если сделать что клиент добавляется один раз в БД
а уже при добавлении из какой либо компании каким то сотрудником  этого же клиента то просто он привязывается к этому клиенту также

Comment: Перечитайте свой вопрос сами и попробуйте перефразировать - ничего не понятно.

Comment: Всё зависит от целей и задач. Мы их не знаем, так что ответить на этот вопрос сможет только заказчик.

Comment: @Andrey Melnikov
на сайте может быть много компаний
У компаний может быть много сотрудников
У сотрудников может быть много клиентов

так вот если сделать что клиент добавленный сотрудником сохранится в БД
если этот же клиент придет до второго сотрудника через время то сохранить его нужно повторно тоесть в БД будет 2 строчки того самого клиента имя и телефон а если будет много компаний и этот клиент к прмиеру будет у 100 компаниях тоесть 100 строк тог самого телефона и имени это нормально?

Comment: Перечитайте моё сообщение ещё раз и прочувствуйте мысль. Если целью ставится сделать агрегатор клиентов и  компаний (сотрудников компаний), тогда нужны общие данные. Если целью ставится как можно больше заманить компаний на свою платформу, при этом для каждой из компаний клиент является ценным активом, то ни одна компания не захочет шарить клиентов. В этом случае проще делать виртуальные хостинги и разносить компании по разным серверам с разными бд, но одинаковой структурой. Что вам нужно???

Comment: @ArchDemon
 ну к примеру, если делать общие данные тоесть одна компания раз добавила клиента он есть в базе , если другая компания введет этот же телефон чтобы зарегистрировать клиента система подскажет что такой клиент уже есть и выдаст его имя фамилию и  т.д. новая то компания не узнает название компании в которой этот клиент есть

Comment: тоесть введя телефон можно узнать только есть ли такой клиент у какой то компании а может быть он у многих, а получить просто можно все его данные а не где он являетсЯ клиентом как на почте к примеру

Comment: Так про это и речь, если человек есть в базе, значит конкурент (конкуренты) его уже окучивают.

Comment: И если после ввода номера телефона вы покажете, что такой клиент уже есть в системе и выведете его  фио, то вы по сути передаете третей стороне информацию: 1) о клиентах компаний из вашей системы 2) личные данные некого клиента. Имхо в системах подобно вашей клиенты должны быть у каждого свои.

Answer (score 1):

Введите дополнительную таблицу для связи клиент-компания. Если клиент новый, то добавляются две записи: в таблицу клиентов и в таблицу связи клиент-компания. Если такой клиент уже есть, то добавляется только запись в таблицу связи.
Компаниям не нужно сообщать о чужих записях в таблице связи.
Но если в таблице связи уже есть запись, что данный клиент уже связан с данной компанией, нужно выводить сообщение, что такой клиент уже есть.

Comment: А если одна компания отредактирует клиента? Другая компания какую запись увидит?

Comment: Здесь есть варианты, но правильным решением будет, чтобы саму запись мог редактировать только клиент (после подтверждения емейла или телефона), а компании редактировали псевдоним, как он виден для них.